# An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occured in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#, stored-procedures

It further states that Procedure or function `spAddOrganization` expects parameter `Organizational_Number` which was not supplied

```
IEnumerable<OrganizationalDetails> OrganizationalDetails
{
    get
    {
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OnlineDBContext"].ToString();
        List<OrganizationalDetails> organization = new List<OrganizationalDetails>();

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spAddOrganization", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;`
            con.Open();

            SqlDataReader myreader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while(myreader.Read())
            { 
                OrganizationalDetails organize = new OrganizationalDetails();
                organize.Organizational_Id = Convert.ToInt32(myreader["Organizational_Id"].ToString());
                organize.Organizational_Number = myreader["Organizational_Number"].ToString();
                organize.Location = myreader["Location"].ToString();
                organize.Organization_Address = myreader["Organizational_Address"].ToString();
                organize.TelephoneNo_Org = myreader["TelephoneNo_Org"].ToString();
                organize.Organizational_Name = myreader["Organizational_Name"].ToString();`ganizational_Name = myreader["Organizational_Name"].ToString();_Name = myreader["Organizational_Name"].ToString();
                organize.Administrator_Name = myreader["Administrator_Name"].ToString();
                organization.Add(organize); 
            }
        }
        return organization;
    }
}
```

The stored procedure is as follows :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spAddOrganization]
    @Organizational_Number nvarchar(50),
    @Location nvarchar(50),
    @Organizational_Address nvarchar(50),
    @TelephoneNo_Org nvarchar(50),
    @Organizational_Name nvarchar(50),
    @Administrator_Name nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Organization_Details(Organizational_Number,Location,Organizational_Address,TelephoneNo_Org,Organizational_Name,Administrator_Name)
    VALUES(@Organizational_Number,@Location,@Organizational_Address,@TelephoneNo_Org,@Organizational_Name,@Administrator_Name)
END
```

Everything seems perfect. I tried googling, tried but found not really understandable answer.

Comment: The error message is fairly self explainatory - AddOrganization is for inserting values, so its expecting values for "@Organizational_Number,@Location,@Organizational_Address,@TelephoneNo_Org,@Organizational_Name,@Administrator_Name" you havent provided any.. in fact you seem to think it will select stuff - you must have picked the wrong stored procedure

Comment: Please format your code snippet in a readable manner and read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Your stored procedure expects parameters (which you are not supplying) and inserts them into a table. Your code is attempting to open a reader, which suggests your code is expecting to call a procedure with a select statement in it. This is a bit disjointed.

Answer (score 0):

Because your Stored Procerure have a Insert Clause you need pass the arguments like this:

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OnlineDBContext"].ToString();

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spAddOrganization", con);
    con.Open();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    SqlParameter[] parameters = new SqlParameter[]
    {
        new SqlParameter("@Organizational_Number", organize.Organizational_Number),
        new SqlParameter("@Location", organize.Location),
        new SqlParameter("@Organizational_Address", organize.Organization_Address),
        new SqlParameter("@TelephoneNo_Org", organize.TelephoneNo_Org),
        new SqlParameter("@Organizational_Name", organize.Organizational_Name),
        new SqlParameter("@Administrator_Name", organize.Administrator_Name)
    };
    cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
    int retorno = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```